# About the $d\mathbf{s}$ notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a vector field that changes with time, that is, written in components:$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x},t)=(F_1(\mathbf{x},t),F_2(\mathbf{x},t),F_3(\mathbf{x},t))$$
where $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ in $ \mathbb{R}^3$.
Now consider:$$\mathbf{r}(u,v,t)=(x(u,v,t),y(u,v,t),z(u,v,t)) $$
where $(u,v)\in D\subset\mathbb{R}^2 $ ($t$ denotes time).
Let $\mathbf{v}(u,v,t)=\partial \mathbf{r}(u,v,t)/\partial t.$

Well, according to my book:$$\int_{\partial D}(\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{v})\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u}\,du+(\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{v})\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\,dv=\int_{\partial D}(\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{v})\cdot d\mathbf{s}$$
(Here $\mathbf{F}$ means $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},t)$).
So it should be:$$d\mathbf{s}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v}dv$$
Could someone explain me why is the latter expression valid? Shouldn't it be $d\mathbf{s}=(du,dv)$?

Comment: You really should try to avoid reusing variable names, especially since the only difference is boldface.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: I believe they are using the distributive property of the dot product, along with using the final expression you wrote to define $s$.